# Select bands with a specified name

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

How can I modify this query to show only bands with the name `"kinks"`? I tried tagging `= #kinks` after `dc:Band` but got no results.

```java
 Query SPARQL_QUERY = QueryFactory.create("" +
           "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +           
           "PREFIX dc: <http://ontologyloc.com/Bands.owl#>" +
           "SELECT DISTINCT ?BandName WHERE { ?BandName rdf:type dc:Band }" 
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your ontology but it could be something like

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>        
PREFIX dc: <http://ontologyloc.com/Bands.owl#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?BandName WHERE {
?BandName rdf:type dc:Band .
?BandName dc:title "kinks" .
}
```

Comment: I'm getting malformed query errors when I attempt to use a . in the middle. Could this be due to using rdf:type in the WHERE section of my query?